# Web Speech API not Working in updated versions of Google Chrome

Tags: google-speech-api

Web Speech API not working in updated versions(not allowed microphone) i.e 61.0.3163.79..If any solution please reply me as early as possible

Answer (score 1):

Are you using HTTPS? I could solve my problem using a self-signed certificate on my server.